# Why does Meteor.users.findOne({username: "test"}) returns an object but replacing "test" with variable that has the same value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

```
var usr = [];
var chatUsers = Session.get("newChatUser");
for ( i in chatUsers )
{
    var a = chatUsers[i];
    var id = Meteor.users.findOne({ username : a });
    usr.push({
        uid : id._id,
        name : a
    });
}
```

Here id becomes undefined when a is "test" but when I run

```
Meteor.users.findOne({ username : "test" })
```

in browser console, it returns the correct object. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you provide a sample data of what gets returned by the session variable?

Comment: This is from Chrome console:
`>> Session.get("newChatUser")`
`[" test "]`
@FardeemMunir

Comment: is this on the client?  If so be sure that the users collection has data before using it.

Comment: The username in the session got spaces at the ends? If so, that's a problem.

Comment: Yup that was the problem, I didn't notice the spaces. @PeppeL-G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`Meteor.users.findOne({ username: a.trim() })`